# Cannot terminate VMware virtual machine running in background

Tags: windows, vmware, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-workstation

I'm using Windows, I've started to use VMware recently and when I installed Ubuntu on it, it stopped responding. I ended the VMware workstation with Windows Task Manager, and when I restarted it, the VM appeared to be powered off in the VMware station, but the VMware Tray Process still displayed the Virtual Machines are running. They captured a lot of CPU usages and memory, especially the VMware Workstation VMX.

The processes seem to be unkillable though I'd tried to kill them in many ways: task manager, taskkill, process explorer, even deleting the virtual machine from the disk (but the only file had been deleted is the vmd file, others still stay and cannot be removed because another process is using it).

I've tried reinstalling the OS 3 times and the same problem still occurs, except for the last time when I booted CD-ROM first with default hardware settings. However, when I changed the memory and the disk space, it stopped responding when I started it, and that problem occured.

Now I've had 3 virtual machine running and always occupies more than 95% CPU usage and I've got no idea how to shut them down and delete them completely. Please show me how, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

1. I restarted my computer
2. When the services hadn't started yet, I deleted the folders which had the running virtual machines, and it works because no process is using them.
3. Finally, no virtual machine is running in the background and the CPU usage is back to normal.